# Smarty + PHP + mySQL comment system not displaying data

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

i'm trying to retrieve the 'name, email, and message' columns from all submitted comments in my comments table and display them on the page but nothing is being displayed. It's weird because I have almost the exact same code for my blog post and it works fine.

php code

```
$sql = "SELECT name, email, message FROM comments"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $sql); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
$data[] = $row;
} 
$tpl->assign('data', $data); 
$tpl->display('comments.tpl');
```

html

```
<table>
    {if $signedin} 
        <tr> 
            <td>Username:</td> 
        </tr> 
        {foreach from=$data item=item key=key} 
        <tr> 
            <td>{$item.name}</td> 
            <td>{$item.email}</td>
            <td>{$item.message}</td>
        <tr> 
        {/foreach} 
    {else}
    Sign in to view comments.
    {/if}
    </table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: adding working code from recipes.php

```
require_once 'config.php';

session_start();

include 'is-signed-in.php';

$data = array(); //initalize a container
    $query = "SELECT * from recipes";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //fetch rows
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row; //push the array inside the row
        }
    }
    $tpl->assign('values', $data);

// Display template
$tpl->display('myrecipes.tpl');
```

recipes.tpl

```
{if $signedin}


{foreach from=$values key=k item=value}
    <p>{$value.user_id_fk}</p>
    <a href="<?php echo url_for('recipes-page.php'); ?>"><h2>{$value.title}</h2></a>
    <p>Date: {$value.submission_date}</p>
    <p>{$value.instructions}</p>
    <p>Category: {$value.category}</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <a href="{$delete}">Delete</a>
{/foreach}
{else}
 You are currently not signed in.
{/if}
```

Comment: Time to add a debug statement:  `echo "Data<pre>", var_export($data, true), "</pre>";` to see what's going on.

Comment: I put it into my comments.php file and nothing happened. I put it into my recipes.php file and get the data info. Maybe something's wrong with my comments.php file?

Comment: Let's see your working code

Comment: @strawberry I added it above.

Comment: @Nick0989, I'm not completely sure you put it, but I would put the debug statement right after the `while` loop that adds data to `$data`.  That way you'll know what if any data was added to `$data`.  If it's empty, your problem is in the MySQL side.  If it is full of data, your problem is on the Smarty side.

Comment: I did have a small error that I fixed, and i put that echo statement. I get Data NULL. But, i do have data in the array Data
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'John Smith',
    'email' => 'jsmith@example.com',
    'message' => 'This was de-lish!',
  ),

Comment: @barenakedcoder, i'm sorry, the data is not null. I had 2 echo's in one...The comments just aren't displaying. No idea why. I've been at it for weeks trying to work with smarty and PHP and it's driving me pretty nuts. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my issue was in my .tpl and nothing was displaying in a table. It really should though, and I did have a stray anchor tab in the h1 element. So this fixed the issue.

```
 <h1>Comments</h1>
            {foreach from=$data item=item key=key} 
            <div> 
                <p>Name: {$item.name}</p> 
                <p>Email: {$item.email}</p>
                <p>Message: {$item.message}</p>
            </div> 
            {/foreach}
```